# How to read a string as HTML in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, string

I want to change a paragraph (with id="p") in HTML when I click the button. The AJAX part already works, but the String that comes in in HTML is not seen as actual HTML code.
What I have now is that a piece of code is read from a .txt file, which looks like this:

```
<p > hello world </p>
```

This is stored in a variable "txt" in js and given to my local server using GET, and then it is retrieved in HTML using the percentage tags, like this:

```
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = $.parseHTML("<%= txt %>");
```

When I click the button, the text changes but it changes to "[object Text]".
I have tried this as well:

```
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "<%= txt %>";
```

But then it changes literally to the code from the txt file, with the tags still visible, while I want js to see it as HTML code, loose the tags and see it as actual HTML. 
However, if I do this, it does work:

```
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "<p> hello world </p>";
```

I read things online that you first need to make a DOM (because I also want to change the HTML afterwards with CSS) or that you need to use .find('#id') on the parseHTML, but so far I've found no good examples. The parseHTML method returns an Array according to the jquery API, but accessing an element of that array has not worked yet either.

Comment: As you mentioned `This is stored in a variable "txt" in js and given to my local server using GET, and then it is retrieved in HTML using the percentage tags, like this:` 
what is the response you get from the server?

Comment: If you get it from your server with `<%= ... %> ` then you need to filter out these characters. You need `<p> Text </p>` to be able to insert it. If you have these weird tags inside it won't work.

Comment: You can use `document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = $.parseHTML("<%= txt %>").html()` to get parsed HTML as string.

Comment: Not sure I follow, Why does your paragraph tag come as "<%= txt %>"?

Comment: The weird tags come from EJS, to get a variable from JS to HTML.

Comment: I don't think the percentage tags are the problem, because when I change the paragraph to "<%= txt %>" I literally get "<p> hello world </p>" on my webpage.